# Windows 10, existing binding.node file cannot be found when running jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-10, electron, jestjs

When running windows 10, on appveyor and as a virtualbox, I'm getting the same, error when running jest tests for my electron app.

```
 The specified module could not be found.
    \\?\C:\Users\User\peruse\app\node_modules\ref\build\Release\binding.node
      Error: The specified module could not be found.
      \\?\C:\Users\User\peruse\app\node_modules\ref\build\Release\binding.node
      at Runtime.requireModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:263:31)
      at bindings (app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:5:47)
```

(https://ci.appveyor.com/project/joshuef/peruse/build/1.0.733/job/fwflo19to9rvt085#L4664)

The thing is... the file itself *exists*, as confirmed by running:

```
dir  \\?\C:\Users\User\peruse\app\node_modules\ref\build\Release\binding.node
```

which results in:

```
-a----         4/9/2018   1:44 AM         157696 binding.node
```

And the application itself runs fine (it's an electron app, compiled via webpack). Only when running tests against the native libs do I get this error. And only in windows. (osx/linux tests are running fine.)

I've tried rebuilding, using `npm` instead of `yarn`, re-installing vs2017 tools via the command line... I'm consistently getting this error on both systems (which is *something*), but I'm stumped as to what to try next...

Jest is being run from the command line.

Jest is configured thus:

```
module.exports = {
    verbose                : true,
    moduleFileExtensions   : ['js', 'jsx', 'json'],
    setupFiles   : ['raf/polyfill','<rootDir>/test/setup.js'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns : ['node_modules'],
    moduleDirectories      : ['app', 'test', 'node_modules', 'app/node_modules'],
    moduleNameMapper       : {
        "electron": "<rootDir>/mocks/electron.js",
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
        "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js",
        "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js",
        '^appPackage$'      : '<rootDir>/package.json',
        '^@actions(.*)$'    : '<rootDir>/app/actions$1',
        '^@components(.*)$' : '<rootDir>/app/components$1',
        '^@containers(.*)$' : '<rootDir>/app/containers$1',
        '^appConstants$'  : '<rootDir>/app/constants.js',
        '^@extensions(.*)$' : '<rootDir>/app/extensions$1',
        '^@logger$'     : '<rootDir>/app/logger.js',
        '^@reducers(.*)$'   : '<rootDir>/app/reducers$1',
        '^@store(.*)$'      : '<rootDir>/app/store',
        '^@utils(.*)$'      : '<rootDir>/app/utils$1'
    }
};
```

[the appveyor config file is here](https://github.com/joshuef/peruse/blob/DevDevin/appveyor.yml).

Any pointers/ideas/things to check *super* appreciated. If more code clarification could be needed, just let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @josh, I'm currently stuck with the same issue - did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Hey @EvgenySorokin, sorry to say we did not. A bunch of digging around various folder structure options yielded nought :(

Comment: @EvgenySorokin any news? stuck up here too with Electron and Windows.

Comment: @Nickensoul Unfortunately not, as a workaround we stopped mocking ibm db module which caused this error and mocked the module that uses it

Comment: @EvgenySorokin, same. We've just mocked native module that cannot be resolved. Strange things. Thanks for the feedback, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with `ibm_db` module on Windows 10 ( but not in a Linux Docker container ):

```
The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\_projects\projectName\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node

  at Runtime._loadModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:572:29)
  at bindings (node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
```

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/239#issuecomment-320604447):

1. Download odbc driver from [IBM site](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/download.do?source=swg-idsoc97&pageType=urx&S_PKG=win64&lang=en_US&dlmethod=http). You might need to register
   at IBM for this.
2. Install this odbc driver by simply extracting the
   content of the package that you downloaded to some folder, for
   examle to "C:\IBMDB2\CLIDRIVER\"
3. Set IBM_DB_HOME environmental variable pointing to folder with drivers. ( to
   "C:\IBMDB2\CLIDRIVER\" if you used that path )
4. Add "%IBM_DB_HOME%\bin" path in "PATH" env variable.
5. Restart or Sing out/Sign in so changes to PATH take effect.
6. Reinstall packages using "npm install" since all those environmental variables are only used during the package installation phase.